# externalIdField in Command Line data loader Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, commandline

We have two objects here.  One is Master and other is child of that master. we have an external field on the master Object. I am trying to perform the Upsert Operation on the Child object with the help of external Field of master object.

I am providing the externalIdfield attribute in config file. But, dataloader is not identifying the field and throwing an error. entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Master__r.External_id__c"

Please suggest .  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there is a little confusion regarding the configuration.

In the config file

```
entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Master__r.External_id__c"
```

tells the dataloader what externalid to use to differentiate the child objects when creating them.

To upsert a relationship in the dataloader you need to specify the mapping in the SDL file for example:

```
Id=Id
Master__r.External_id__c=Master__r\:External_id__c
```

Please note these relationship mappings are only available for upserts, not for inserts or updates as far as I am aware.  You may find [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Additional_detail) helpful too.

Comment: Any links that include command line instruction?

Comment: I think this may be what you are looking for: https://code.google.com/p/dataloadercliq/