# Data Loader from Command Line - Upsert Opportunity - Indicate Acccount Relationship Field

Tags: data-loader, commandline

I'm using the command line of the data loader to upsert opportunities from an outside system to keep them in synch. I have a column with the Salesforce Opportunity ID, as well as, the associated Salesforce Account ID.

What entry key to I use in the bean to indicate these columns?

When using the Data Loader GUI, you are prompted to choose the Opportunity matching field (I'm bringing in the external id to salesforce and related object external ID for Accounts.

```
<entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="ExternalID__c"/>
```

How would I indicate the account id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check answer of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/externalidfield-in-command-line-data-loader-salesforce).

Basically it says , In the config file

```
entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Master__r.External_id__c"
```

tells the dataloader what externalid to use to differentiate the child objects when creating them.

To upsert a relationship in the dataloader you need to specify the mapping in the SDL file for example:

```
Id=Id
Master__r.External_id__c=Master__r\:External_id__c
```

These relationship mappings are only available for upserts, not for inserts or updates.